# type missmatch error to ceil function in classic asp

Tags: mysql, types, asp-classic, ceil

```
    sql_logcout="select count(*) as totcount from tbllogincount where companylogin='"&RECRS("companylogin")&"' and (logindate>'"&fromdate&"' and logindate<'"&todate&"') "
    rslogins.open sql_logcout,con,0,3
    if not rslogins.EOF then
      totlogins=rslogins("totcount")
      do while not rslogins.EOF 

        'on below line i am getting error
        avglogin=ceil(totlogins/10)
        avglogin=ceil(avglogin)

        rslogins.movenext
      loop
    end if
    rslogins.close      

    avglogin=ceil(totlogins/10)
    avglogin=ceil(avglogin)

    rslogins.movenext
  loop
end if
rslogins.close
```

in above code I get count 0 and I am getting error on `avglogin=ceil(totlogins/10)`

error is as below

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch
>
> /admin/member_email.asp, line 200

What is the problem there? I had tried by using `CStr` or `CInt` but still its same. Please help me to solve this error. I am using Classic ASP with MySQL.

Comment: This is a mess you only posted part of your code, it's obvious once formatted that there is a query being run inside a loop, this is not a good practice and can often be avoided by joining tables in the SQL query or better database design.

Comment: ok will edit post and add whole page code below

Comment: Just a quick note, here, ashwini - your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, so you should [consider remedying this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=classic+asp+sql+injection).

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to ensure that there's a value in the data you're reading from your tables.

Try:

```vbs
If Not IsNull(rslogins("totcount")) And Not rslogins("totcount") Is Nothing Then
    Do While ...
        ....
    Loop
End If
```

Personally, I prefer the quick and the dirty method of a quick cast, but I'm sure someone will spurn me for it...

```vbs
If rslogins("totcount") & "" <> "" Then
    ....
End If
```

It's your choice!

Background reading:

- http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/vbnothing
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbchw6hz(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_isnull.asp
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_isempty.asp
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ake1y5wx(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.w3schools.com/asp/vbscript_ref_keywords.asp

Comment: I won't spurn you for the quick cast but I will for referencing w3schools...Better references then that @Paul

Comment: @Lankymart: Ha!  I know, but they have improved considerably and I tend to quote beginner sites to beginners, but notice, also, that I have included links to M$.